# Retrieve all files from all folders and subfolders in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library

I want to retrieve all the files which are last modified in a particular document library. I will not be able to find out that how many folders are there in the document library. User can select any of its library.

I want to show only documents in descending order of modified date. Currently I am checking while retrieving items if the current item is folder, if it is folder I loop through that folder and retrieve all files from that. If that folder has also subfolder I will have to again loop through that. I don't know till how many level should I go.
Below is the code which I am using right now:

```
int temp = 0;
SPList cList = spWeb.Lists[listName];
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
spQuery.RowLimit = 4;
SPListItemCollection collection = cList.GetItems(spQuery);
if (collection.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SPListItem cItem in collection)
    {
        if (cItem.Folder == null)
        {
            do something...!
            temp++;
        }
        else
        {
            //SPList cList_temp = spWeb.Lists[listName];
            SPQuery spQuery_temp = new SPQuery();
            spQuery_temp.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
            spQuery_temp.Folder = cItem.Folder;
            spQuery_temp.RowLimit = 4;
            SPListItemCollection collection_temp = cList.GetItems(spQuery_temp);
            if (collection_temp.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem item in collection_temp)
                {
                    if (temp < 4)
                    {
                        if (item.Folder != null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        do something...!
                        temp++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (temp == 4)
            break;
    }
}
```

Using this code I am able to get only first level folder's files. I want to retrieve latest 4 documents from the library. That's why I have used `temp` variable.
Is there any batter option than this?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your `SPQuery` object, you can set the scope in the `ViewAttributes` property, as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewattributes.aspx

```
...
SPQuery spQuery_temp = new SPQuery();
spQuery_temp.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
spQuery_temp.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
...
```

With this recursive scope setting, the query will retrieve all items from the target location regardless of which subfolder they are in.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
 SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPList list = web.Lists[“Shared Documents”];

    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    //Condition to check the item type is folder or not
    query.Query = “<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=’FSObjType’/><Value Type=’Lookup’>1</Value></Eq></Where>”;
    //Get all the items including subfolders from the list 

query.ViewAttributes = “Scope=’RecursiveAll'”;

//Retrieve the items based on Query 

SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
string folderDetails=“”;

    //Get the name and Url for the folder 

    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
    {
    folderDetails += “Folder Name:” + item.Name + “<br/>Folder URL:” + web.Url + “/” + item.Url + “<br/>”; 
    }
```

http://www.ktskumar.com/2009/07/retrieve-all-folders-from-list/