# Retrieve all List items in library caml

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, caml

I have reference to a document library. I want to now create a CAML to pull out every item contained within this document library.

I can't seem to figure out the CAML in which to do this. Every CAML I've looked online wants you to give a field reference within the caml.

All I want is all list items present in the doc lib.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can check this question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178115/retrieve-all-files-from-all-folders-and-subfolders-in-document-library

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

If you want to retrieve all list items just don't put anything for the CamlQuery.

```
private static ListItemCollection GetListItems(List docLibrary, ClientContext ctx)
        {
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            var listItems = docLibrary.GetItems(query);
            ctx.Load(listItems);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return listItems;
        }
```